# eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented message in logcat

Tags: java, android, xml

```
03-08 18:08:11.635    2265-2281/com.example.robert.umpirerestartfrombeginning W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-08 18:08:11.635    2265-2281/com.example.robert.umpirerestartfrombeginning W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c20800, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

It isn't throwing any errors, but I am wary of continuing before I solve this problem. I am using Android Studio to develop and I have no idea what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this in the emulator only or on an actual device as well?

Comment: Are you directly using OpenGL?

Comment: I am only doing this on the emulator. My device will not support the drivers needed. As for the OpenGL I don't believe I am directly using it.

Comment: I see errors like this as well.  I don't think it is something you need to worry about.